# Push a window when a row is selected

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, titanium, appcelerator

I am new to Titanium Studio. I am trying some samples in TableViews. How to push a new window when a row is selected in the tableView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a new window in table row's click event.

some thing like this,

```
row.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
      height:480,
      width:320,
      url:'sample.js'
    });

       win.open({modal: true});
});
```

Comment: there really is now need to set the height and width, if you don't add it, it'll just be full screen so it works on all devices properly.

Comment: Or use this instead ... Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth to get the width of window and Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight to get the height of window

Comment: But still, thats the default value ;)

Answer (score 2):

And if you want to push window with navigation bar in iPhone than i think you should use modal window. In the above example replace line,

```
win.open();
```

with

```
win.open({modal:true});
```